# moving data from a web app on one vagrant box to another

Tags: vagrant

I've got a web app running on one vagrant box. however I've started building a different app to do the same job in another vagrant box. I'd like to keep the original box working as is so that I can compare results between the two or in case I need to reimport the data to the second box. What is the best way to connect the two together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the application data on the host machine. The `/vagrant` folder always points to the `Vagrantfile`-folder of your host machine.

Then copy/move the necessary data or use `rsync` to sync data across two folders on the host.

Alternative:

- Give both Vagrant boxes a static IP
- Use rsync to sync data selectively between bot machines
- Write bash-files for automatic execution.

> https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps